# Angular security in $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

For our app when a user logged in we are issuing him a token which is stored in session and we are using $rootScope to store his details.

This what we are doing

```
if(sessionStorage.loggedIn && sessionStorage.token){
  addonService.get({
    customer_token : sessionStorage.token
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
        $rootScope.user = data.user;
        $rootScope.address = data.address;              
  });
}
```

Is this procedure safe? Is there any way hacker can hijack user variable from $scope? If this is not the best practice how can I make my code better?

Comment: This question is broader than Angular, and probably belongs on [security exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use session/local storage?